# My NGINX wildcard does not accept arguments in proxy_pass

Tags: docker, nginx, proxypass

Below is the configuration for my http proxy server. It successfully redirects, except for arguments put in get requests. For example: `?format=json` appended at the end.  Can someone explain why the wildcard isn't working for arguments and perhaps what I need to add to make it work?

```
http {

    # Docker
    resolver 127.0.0.11 ipv6=off valid=5s;

    server {
        listen 8005;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;

        set $backend http://backend:8000;
        location ~ ^/api/backend/?(.*)$ {
            resolver 127.0.0.11 ipv6=off valid=5s;
            proxy_pass $backend/$1;
        }

}
```

Comment: Both `location` and `rewrite` directives working with the *normalized* URI which doesn't include the query part of request. The query part of request can be accessed via `$args` or `$query_string` variables (these two are synonyms). What do you want exactly to achieve? Give an URI example and how do you want it to be passed to your backend.

Comment: Nginx uses a normalised URI which does not include the query string. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html#simple_php_site_configuration). The arguments are already available as `$args`, so you do not need to capture them.